# Configure htaccess for Slim Framework

Tags: .htaccess, slim

I have this directories structure on my server:

```
site.com/www/index.php
site.com/www/api/Slim
site.com/www/api/index.php
```

I want configure Slim for use as rest-api interface in 'api' folder. How can i configure htaccess in api folder for it?

Note. in www/ i have other htaccess and index.php for my project, i think this should not prevent. htaccess in www folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set your RewriteBase to folder where Slim application is located.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This one is the I am using.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```